# How do you style an options page for a pluging using the wordpress options API?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation, wordpress-admin

I'm coding my first wordpress plugin. I've created an options page with a few options using the wordpress options API functions `add_settings_section()` and `add_settings_field()`.

Everything works fine so far but all fields on the settings page are in one column. I'd like to style the options page a little "nicer" but I can't find an API for it.

How do I for instance arrange the settings sections and settings field in two columns using `<div>` or an html `<table>`? The wordpress API seems to create it's own table structure.

Thank you!

Comment: You don't need API for styling... Just enque stylesheet on the admin page and sort it out that way.

Comment: I know how to create a stylesheet but the wordpress API puts all options fields in a single column table. How do I break that schema?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I handled the same issue.
To give context here is an image of the columns that I wanted.  [image]

In my implementation I removed `do_settings_sections('my_page');`  and used raw HTML instead.

```
<form action="options.php" method="post">
<?php
settings_errors();
settings_fields('my_page_settings');
// do_settings_sections('my_page');
?>

<table class="form-table">

    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Update Mode</th>
        <td><?php $this->my_page_render_update_mode_field() ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Update</th>
        <td style="padding-top:0px !important;">
            <table class="form-table">
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-top:0px !important;"><?php $this->my_page_render_page_items_field() ?></td>
                    <td style="padding-top:0px !important;"><?php $this->my_page_render_post_field() ?></td>
                    <td style="padding-top:0px !important;"><?php $this->my_page_render_product_items_field() ?></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" style="margin-bottom:10px !important;" name="submit" class="button button-primary button-md" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Save'); ?>" />
```